# How can I replace opened brackets from end of line to new line using sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed, osx, regular-expression

I have many files with wrong opened { brackets from end of line and need to replace it to new line by conditon `[a-z)] [{]|[a-z)][{].`

input example:

```
public class Test {

}
```

expected output:

```
public class Test 
{

}
```

What is wrong in my solution?

```
sed -e '/[a-z)] [{]|[a-z)][{]/s/{/N{/g' *.java -r
```

Comment: Can you provide samples of your input and your expected output? Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing this on a Mac, this `sed` will do it:
`sed 's/{$/\'$'\n{/'`

Example:

```
echo "public class Test {

}" | sed 's/{$/\'$'\n{/'
public class Test 
{

}
```

If you want to edit the file "in place" execute this command:

```
sed -i "" 's/{$/\'$'\n{/' java
```

Result:

```
cat java 
public class Test 
{

}
```

[Here](http://nlfiedler.github.io/2010/12/05/newlines-in-sed-on-mac.html) is a reference on inserting newlines in `sed` on Mac.

---

Tested in OS X 10.11.6

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this command

```
sed -e s/{/\\n{/g *.java
```

it will replace any `{` by a `\n{` and show the output in the screen.
To replace the text in the files you can use the option in-place

```
sed -i s/{/\\n{/g *.java
```

Comment: Sirst command put \n as characters without replacing to new line, second show error ' sed: 1: "Test.java": invalid command code T

Comment: are you sure you type double \ before n. this command worked on the example you made

Comment: ➜  example sed -i '' s/{/\\n{/g *.java                   
➜  example cat Test.java
public class Test n{
    
}

Comment: ok try using double quotes (not single) sed -e "s/{/\\n{/g" *.java

Comment: OP is using a Mac, and therefore BSD `sed`.